# Como multiplicar um caractere "X" quantas vezes quiser?

Tags: .net, string, char

Existe algum método que multiplique um caractere "X" quantas vezes eu quiser?
exemplo:

tenho o caractere "P"

> P x 5 = "PPPPP"

Existe algum método pronto em .Net?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sim, existe, basta construir a *string* indicando o número de vezes que deseja:

```
var texto = new String('P', 5);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AKwSs7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mvgqAM). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/MultipleChars.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_).

Answer (score 6):

#### Em VB.NET

<sub>É a mesma coisa que a resposta do @Maniero, porém em VB.NET, já que não foi especificada nenhuma linguagem.</sub>

```
Dim texto = New String("P", 5)
```

Veja no [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cGMfgs)